# Does the unsigned keyword affect the result of sizeof?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof, unsigned

Do C and C++ guarantee that the unsigned equivalent of a type has the same size?

Example:

```
size_t size = sizeof(unsigned int);
```

Is the `unsigned` completely moot here?

Comment: I'd be amazed if sizeof(int) ever did not equal sizeof(unsigned). I recommend trust-but-verify.

Comment: While it's redundant, I think it's recommended to use `sizeof(unsigned int)` if it's about space for `unsigned int` to avoid confusion.

Comment: In terms of Psychology - You want the size of X (whatever X is) - So just be explicit. Then programming you will always be right whatever X is - (unsigned int, class Cabbage ...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both languages guarantee that signed and unsigned variants of a corresponding standard integer type have the same size.

C++, committee draft n3337, 3.9.1/3:

> 3 For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) standard un-
>   signed integer type: “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, “unsigned long int”,
>   and “unsigned long long int”, **each of which occupies the same amount of storage** and has the same
>   alignment requirements (3.11) as the corresponding signed integer type45; that is, each signed integer type
>   has the same object representation as its corresponding unsigned integer type. [...]

For C, the wording is very similar

Taken from draft n1570, 6.2.5/6:

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned
>   integer type (designated with the keyword unsigned) **that uses the same amount of
>   storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements.** The type
>   _Bool and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer
>   types are the standard unsigned integer types. The unsigned integer types that
>   correspond to the extended signed integer types are the extended unsigned integer types.
>   The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called unsigned integer
>   types.

Comment: Excellent answer, nice to see an actual citation.

Comment: The initial "yes" in your answer is confusing since OP worded the question subject and first line of the question body in reverse. :-)

Comment: I guess you mean `n1570` ?

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, that's a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really obsolete, more like redundant. The standard does guarantee signed and unsigned variations of a type to have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put in some code like this

```
{
char s1[1 + sizeof(int) - sizeof(unsigned int)];
char s2[1 + sizeof(unsigned int) - sizeof(int)];
}
```

(probably only in debug builds)

This will give you a compile time failure if they were ever different sizes.

I do this occasionally for highly (typedef)ed code I'm refactoring.

But unsigned and signed varieties are always the same size.

Comment: `assert(sizeof(signed int) == sizeof(unsigned int))` accomplishes the same with greater readability.

Comment: But isn't that a run-time failure? I want to block compilation!

Comment: For C++11 you can use [`std::static_assert(sizeof(signed int) == sizeof(unsigned int), "size mismatch");`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) to get a compile time error.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, C11 has the same feature, without `std::`, naturally.

Comment: @JensGustedt nice to know since i don't spend much time in C anymore.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious `static_assert` is a declaration, not a class. You don't prefix it with `std::`.

Comment: @Angew Oops...too much typing of `std`